# Link two attributes to one form element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to have one select which specifies the value of two model attributes. Therefore if you were to select "yes" on a drop-down it would set the value of attribute a and attribute b to "yes" when the form is submitted. Although the below doesnt work it might help explain what I mean:

```
= f.select :trial, :free , [['Yes', 'true'], ['No', 'false']], {}, class: 'selectpicker mandatory'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that.

What you can do instead, is upon validating the object set the `free` attribute equal to `trial` (that was set by selecting from a dropdown).

Comment: Yeah I had been using that approach but thought it would be good to take the other approach. Alas it is not possible so will go with my original approach. Thanks anyway.